# verilog: how to operate the array which size is parameterized

Tags: verilog

I have a question about the operation for multiple arrays. The code below works well for the fixed number of arrays

```
wire [size-1:0] data [0:3];
wire [size-1:0] result;

assign result = data[0]&data[1]&data[2]&data[3];
```

But how can I deal with it for a parameterized number arrays like

```
wire [size-1:0] data [0:num-1];
wire [size-1:0] result;

assign result = ????
```

any ideas or suggestions, hope you guys have some simple answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is something like the following:

```
always @* begin
  result = 0;
  for (i=0; i<num; i=i+1) begin
    result = result & data[i];
  end    
end
```

However this has two potential issues:

1. It's not technically legal to use an array in a sensitivity list in verilog. I've read that *most* simulators/synthesis tools will do what you expect with that sensitivity list, but some of them may not.
2. Depending on the size of your array, this may or may not be synthesizable. Large arrays would typically be implemented as RAMs, and you can generally only read out one value of the array per clock cycle, so you wouldn't be able to trivially `and` them all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
wire [size-1:0] data[0:num-1];
wire [size-1:0] data_tmp[0:num-1];
wire [size-1:0] result;

generate
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < num; i=i+1) begin
        if (i == 0)
            assign data_tmp[i] = data[i];
        else if (i == num-1)
            assign result = data_tmp[i-1] & data[i];
        else
            assign data_tmp[i] = data_tmp[i-1] & data[i];
    end
endgenerate
```